# An error appears in the translation function in the Model Derivative tutoria

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative

I am doing Step-by-Step Tutorials of Model Derivative API from  Auto Desk-forge.
https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/tutorials/translate-to-obj/task3-translate-source-file/

Successfully completed task 1 to task 4

[image: Task 3 – Translate Source File screen]

However, it is not visible in the viewer.

[image: Viewer result screen]

Please provide a solution....

Answer (score 0):

Check the console in your browser's [dev tools](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools) to see if there are any warnings or errors indicating what went wrong.

Also, I'd suggest that you take a look at the basic [View Models](https://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/tutorials/viewmodels) tutorial on the https://learnforge.autodesk.io website. That one will help you build a complete Forge application where you can upload, translate, and preview your designs via a simple UI.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to see your model in the viewer, you need to translate your file in `SVF` or `SVF2`. In your request, the translation is in `obj`. Take a look at [SVF Translation](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/tutorials/prep-roominfo4viewer/option1/) if you want an example of `SVF` translation request or follow the **learnforge** link provided in Petr's answer.